# problema al desplegar aplicacion

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Buenas estoy poniendo en produccion mi aplicacion hecha react+laravel,pero a la hora de ejecutar el comando de npm run prod me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya corri el comando en mi local y normal compila,pienso que es por el servidor que esta en linux.
el comando completo es:
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"

Comment: Quieres compilar el js en el servidor? Instalaste las dependencias? Por que no subes directamente el js compilado en tu local?

Comment: solo es un avance para que el cliente lo vea, si lo ago de mi local cada vez que quiero compilar en produccion seria de mi local y en el servidor eliminar los compilados ,por eso quiero compilar en el servidor

Comment: no importa si el sistema operativo del servidor es un linux, pero tendrá que tener instalado node y npm para que puedas instalar las dependencias del frontend y luego compilar tu js y scss

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si tiene instalado todo, el problema es que no encuentra los archivos